# Import data from MySQL to elasticsearch with logstash after preprocessing

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I am trying to import data from  MySQL to elasticsearch using logstash, everything works fine and I have all the data imported well. However, one of the fields in MySQL called "metadata" is following a specific pattern like this "firstname_lastname_yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" so for example this is one of the values it may take "Mark_Karlos_2018-02-23 15:19:55", at the moment this field is imported to Elasticsearch as it is, what I want to do is to have this field as three fields in Elasticsearch "first_name", "last_name", "time". Is this possible to be done with Logstash config file? If not is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the grok filter:

```
grok {
    match => {"metadata"=> "%{GREEDYDATA:first_name}_%{GREEDYDATA:last_name}_%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}"}
}
```

To help you with the grok filter:

[Official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

[Existing patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)

[To test your patterns](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match)

Comment: Thank you, it works! but what if the datetime has a custom format let's say my field looks like this  "firstname_lastname_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" then using the same example in the question "Mark_Karlos_20180223_151955" 
how can I modify the last part to read this "custom" datetime format?

Comment: You can use `GREEDYDATA` instead, like this: `%{GREEDYDATA:time}`